# Filewriter prints twice in a file

Tags: java, file, filewriter

```
public listaRegistros almacenesAceptados(listaRegistros lr) {

    int i, j, l;
    registro r = new registro();
    listaRegistros aAceptados = new listaRegistros();
    totales = lr.getSize();

    for (i = 0; i < totales; i++) {
        r = lr.get(i);
        l = r.getSize();
        if ((r.get(1).getContenido().contains("null")) || (r.get(2).getContenido().contains("null")) || (r.get(3).getContenido().contains("null"))) {
            aAceptados.quitar(r);
            cancelados++;

        } else {
            aAceptados.addRegistro(r);
        }
    }

    ArchivoLogXX();
    return aAceptados;
}

public void ArchivoLogXX() {

    int b = (int) cancelados;
    File ArchivoLogXX = new File("ArchivoLogXX.txt");
    boolean append=true;
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(ArchivoLogXX, append);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write("\n:::::Almacenes:::::");
        bw.write("\nHay " + b + " almacenes erroneos, revise el codigo postal, la direccion y el numero.");
        bw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {

        fnf.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException io) {

        io.printStackTrace();
    }

}


}
```

I have this classes, and I want to print just once in the file ArchivoLogXX, but I don´t know why, it prints the same twice.

I think the problem is in the append, but I really need it because if the file is not empty I want to continue writing on it.

Comment: By means of an example, what do you mean by `it prints the same twice.`? What gets printed twice?

Comment: Are you sure `ArchivoLogXX()` is only called once?

Comment: double check in the code for almacenesAceptados() and ArchivoLogXX() calls any time any one is call you get another 2 lines in the file

Comment: It prints twice what is after bw.write. In prints it twice in the same file, and i want to print it just once.

Comment: anyone can help me? i have similar code in other class, but without variable append and it writes once well